# What would be best dedicated server for my Magento 1.9.3.x

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

I need your EXPERT advise on purchasing a linux debian server -   as DEDICATE SERVER,

i am currently  using the debian server for my magento 1.9.3.x  store  which has about 2000 users daily  visitors on the website...

my current specifications are : 64 GB DDR4 RAM , 500 GB  NVMe  SSD disk ,  Intel® Core™ i7-6700 Quad-Core

i wont to migrate to all the same specification only  procesor will be better:  AMD Ryzen 7 3700X Octa-Core

will there be a any higly noticable speed in my website opening and speed ?  if i change to this better procesor  maybe boost in my mysql ?

please give me your honest advise  this server is 1x more expensiver for me is it worth the money to invest ?  ore should i stay where i am....

thanks  for your time & help  i apriciate it.

Comment: i have too many extensions which are dependent of the 1.X this would be a disaster to make and alot of mone to invest...  i just invested alot of mone to upgrade this i cannot just move somewhere else this is not a forum

Comment: To improve existing setup, additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for Linux/Unix limits list, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: You would be safe to ignore the comment of Feb 11 at 16:33 since you have 64GB or RAM and NVME is better/faster than SSD (and more expensive).